# In order to use eConnect 11.0 for Dynamics GP 2010, does the eConnect windows service have to be installed on the client computer?

Tags: wcf, dynamics-gp, econnect

I am working on a Windows Forms app that will integrate with Dynamics GP 2010, using the eConnect WCF service.

The eConnect Windows service is defaulted to only have the net.pipe binding, which would indicate that every client machine that will run my Windows Forms app will need to also have the eConnect Windows service also installed.

Is it possible to use the eConnect Windows service remotely?  So that it can be installed on one server and have several client machines connect to it? I was thinking of modifying the config file for the Windows service to add a net.tcp binding, but I'm not sure if that would be supported by the service and Googling hasn't turned up much.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a custom web service and install it in on the same domain where gp web service is installed  and use this web service as a bridge between gp web service and your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, in order for your windows form app to work with the eConnect code, you will need to install it on each of the clients.  However, there are available web services that you can reach remotely, outside of the eConnect tool for GP 2010.  It's either do it that way, or install it on a single web server, and change your application from Windows form, to web forms.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can setup econnect on the server and add a HTTP reference in addition to the net pipe.  this will allow econnect to be called from a client that does not have econnect.